# Creation and Annihilation Commutator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, differentiation, commutator

I am reading Quantum Mechanics An Introduction by W. Greiner 2nd Edition, and I can't produce the Creation & Annihilation Commutator result of 1 by using the definition given on page 123 :

$$ a^- := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( x + \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\right)$$

$$ a^+ := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( x - \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\right)$$

My result for $[a^-,a^+]  := a^-a^+ - a^+a^-$ is not 1, but is instead $1-x \frac{ \partial }{\partial x}$.

My working is as follows :

$$a^-a^+ = \frac{1}{2}\left(x^2 - x \frac{ \partial}{\partial x} + \frac{ \partial}{\partial x}{x} - \frac{ \partial ^2}{\partial x^2}{x}\right)$$

$$a^+a^- = \frac{1}{2}\left(x^2 + x \frac{ \partial}{\partial x} - \frac{ \partial}{\partial x}{x} - \frac{ \partial ^2}{\partial x^2}{x}\right)$$

with

$$\frac{ \partial}{\partial x} x = 1.$$

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}x = 1 + x \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ since $x$ is here used as a multiplicative operstor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To spot the mistake, you can try evaluating $a^- a^+f(x)$ and $a^+a^-f(x)$ for some function $f(x)$. Instead of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} x$, you would have $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (xf(x))$.